# Convert string value into variable value - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string variable: `id = '1';` 
I want to make a variable that holds the value of `data.img + id + .dispWidth` without making it a string.

For example, if `id = '7';` then `dw = data.img7.dispWidth;` 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['img' + id].dispWidth` should do it. Although at that point you should probably consider whether you don't actually want an array.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to use dynamic property keys

```
dw = data['img' + id].dispWidth;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked like a charm.